# Can a level 16 draconic sorcerer maintain their dragon wings (from the Dragon Wings bloodline spell) indefinitely?

Tags: spells, sorcerer, pathfinder-2e, duration

Draconic sorcerers gain the focus spell [Dragon Wings](https://2e.aonprd.com/Spells.aspx?ID=501) at 5th level.

When the spell is heightened to 8th level, "the duration increases to ten minutes."

If a sorcerer has a focus point at time T, and expends it by casting Dragon Wings, then when do they regain that focus point?

From the description of [bloodline spells](https://2e.aonprd.com/Bloodlines.aspx):

> You refill your focus pool during your daily preparations, and you can
> regain 1 Focus Point by spending 10 minutes using the Refocus
> activity. Unlike other characters, you don't need to do anything
> specific to Refocus, as the power of the blood flowing through your
> veins naturally replenishes your focus pool.

Does this imply that the sorcerer can't maintain their wings indefinitely, as (presumably) they would cast the spell in combat, and thus would have some time (e.g. a couple of rounds) where they weren't engaged in the Refocus activity? I.e. they would start refocusing at some time T + x, where x > 0, and they would only regain the Wings at T + x + 10m ?

I want to say this is correct, but I also like the notion of the sorcerer gaining those wings for as long as they reduce their focus pool by 1, to 'keep it up'. But I'd appreciate your thoughts.

Comment: Do you want the wings kept for aesthetic reasons? Or mechanic reasons?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### A Draconic Sorcerer would have to recast Dragon Wings

The result is, as you note, that they will not *immediately* regain the Focus Point to re-cast it and the Wings will be "off" at least 1 round before they're able to cast them again without spending a second Focus Point.

However, it is unclear whether combat affects the Sorcerer's ability to regain their Focus Point spent after 10 minutes. This is actually built into the [Exploration](https://2e.aonprd.com/Traits.aspx?ID=66) tag that [Refocus](https://2e.aonprd.com/Actions.aspx?ID=71) uses. Emphasis added.

> An activity with this trait takes more than a turn to use, and can **usually be used only during exploration mode.**

So, the *usual* result is that the Refocus is interrupted.

- If cast in combat, the rest of combat adds to the time before the spell can be re-cast with the 'same' Focus Point
- If they engage in combat after exploring with Refocus for 5 minutes, it will be another 10 minutes after that combat (approximately 15 since last casting Dragon Wings) before that Focus Point replenishes

However, a GM can rule that, because the Sorcerer's blood is always doing its sorcerous recharging, the Sorcerer can *continue* to Refocus along side any other actions including Encounter actions/activities. The result of this would be a mere 1 turn difference between the end of one Dragon Wings and the ability to recast it with the same spell (and likely at that point hand-waving that they are on as long as they maintain 1 spent Focus Point).

---

This GM would rule that, as long as it didn't adversely affect play, that they could maintain the wings as long as they had the Focus Point to do so. By level 16, this isn't a game breaking advantage and would be a cool benefit for the player. I don't see any Bloodline Focus spells that would be 'too' powerful if allowed to be used every 10 minutes regardless of combat. I would, however, inform the player that it is only a standing ruling and Paizo clarifying that Sorcerers could not do this (or player(s) attempting to 'break the game' using the ruling) could result in that changing.

Comment: All sounds reasonable, and pretty much in line with my understanding. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Sorcerer's class feature does not stop them from needing to use the Refocus activity, it just gives them an open door of flavor rather than requiring a specific activity like praying or reflecting on nature. They still need to spend the 10 minutes doing nothing but taking the Refocus activity.

Comment: @Delioth That's not true for anyone using Refocus. "These deeds can usually overlap with other tasks that relate to the source of your focus spells. For instance, a cleric with focus spells from a good deity can usually Refocus while tending the wounds of their allies, and a wizard of the illusionist school might be able to Refocus while attempting to Identify Magic of the illusion school."

Comment: It's only restriction are Concentration (you must be conscious and not raging or similar) and Exploration (which I address).